Unable to access the existing drive folder using the drive.file scope
We have been using the Google Drive REST API to access the metadata of a file using the fileId. The basic API URL is:  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}'
We have created Google Drive folders using the 'auth/drive' scope with our app. Since this scope is considered restricted, we are transitioning to the 'auth/drive.file' scope. However, we are encountering a "404 : File Not Found" error when accessing the already created Google Drive folders.
We expect the Google Drive Get File API v3 to function as it does with the auth/drive scope. Specifically, we anticipate receiving successful metadata responses for files.
Below is the response we are receiving:
RESPONSE DATA:  {
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "File not found: 1hsOTQhT1T_fGuK6NFN4IuaYqq0qH.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "File not found: 1hsOTQhT1T_fGuK6NFN4IuaYqq0H.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "notFound",
        "location": "fileId",
        "locationType": "parameter"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Is there any other alternative way to resolve this issue?

Learn to use markdown to format your posts.
